# SMTP Address re-use in Office 365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

About 6 hours ago I removed an SMTP address from one of our users using the Office365 admin portal. I want to attach this address to a new shared mailbox.

Trying to create the new mailbox with the address is just giving me

```
Email addresses need to be unique and this one is already being used by the pgreen.
```

I understand that there is a time period for the removal of the address from the original recipient to propagate but I thought that was measured in minutes, not hours. Certainly after 6 hours I'd expect it to be clear, so now I'm wondering if I've done something wrong.

Checking the recipient from the O365 powershell module show the address is no longer associated.

The address removed was pgreen@somethinggroup.com from the recipient pgreen.

```
PS> (get-recipient pgreen).EmailAddresses    smtp:pgreen@somethingfundraising.onmicrosoft.com
SMTP:pgreen@somethingfundraising.com
SIP:pgreen@somethingfundraising.com
smtp:pgreen@somethingtm.com
smtp:Pfullname.Green@somethingfundraising.com
smtp:Pfullname.Green@somethinggroup.com
```

Email sent to the removed address [pgreen@somethinggroup.com] is returned undeliverable `pgreen wasn't found at somethinggroup.com`

I can't think of any other way to identify if/what/where is going on. Is it just a case of waiting it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the alias pgreen@somethinggroup.com as an alias of the shared mailbox. Don't try to create the shared mailbox with that alias directly

Your default address policy must come block you

Once the shared mailbox is created with a dummy email address, add the one you want to use as an alias, then set that as the primary address and delete the dummy address.